# Unity 5, Input.touchCount, сбрасывает значения каждый кадр.

Tags: c#, unity3d

Если nosik = 1, при нажатии на тач срабатывает dog, всё окей.
Если nosik = 2, то на тач нужно нажать 2 раза очень быстро, практически одновременно, иначе dog не запустится. 
Если nosik = 3, нужно нажимать еще быстрее. Короче, я так понял что значения input.touchCount сбрасываются в каждом кадре. Можно как нибудь сделать чтобы оно считалось нормально, чтобы если, например, nosik = 3, можно было бы нажать медленно 3 раза на тач и был бы вызван dog?

```
void Update () {
    gts = Input.touchCount;
    if (gts == nosik) { dog(); }
    if(gts > nosik) { dog(); }
}
```

Comment: Вам же никто не мешает сделать счетчик и считать сколько раз юзер нажал. Можете написать небольшой класс или метод, в котором опишите: сколько допускается времени между тапами, чтоб это считалось как подряд, а также через какое время сбрасывать счетчик.... хотя даже только последнее значение и понадобиться... прошло больше назначенного времени? тогда сброс счетчика. Иначе при TouchPhase.Began прибавлять счетчик и таймер (который следит сколько времени прошло)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Мне бы его вообще не сбрасывать до того как приложение не закроют. Как именно это сделать? Именно в отдельном классе?

Comment: Ну тогда просто заведите переменную счетчика и каждый раз когда `TouchPhase.Began` прибавляйте его..... всё.....хотя судя по задаче - надо делать как я говорю..............а `touchCount` это не сколько раз подряд нажали, а сколько тачей было одновременно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пока не понимаю.  Переменная счётчика вроде уже есть `gts`, а куда именно поставить `TouchPhase.Began`?

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под словом "тач" тогда? Непонятно. Тач это вроде как прикосновение. Или у вас это что-то другое значит? А то в данный момент какая-то несуразица. Вы считаете колчичество тачей и если их определенное количество то надо нажать на тач О_о

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нашел вот такое и оно работает. Но только для мышки. Как сделать такое под тач?  `void OnMouseDown()
    {
        gts++;
        
    }`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Подразумеваю, что мне нужен счётчик касаний, без обнуления.

Comment: У тачей есть фазы.....https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html .........`Began --> A finger touched the screen.` .......вот его и надо учитывать значит вместо мышки....... если кто-то коснулся, то прибавлять счетчик `gts+`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я уже прочитал эту статью, спасибо! Вот, непонятно теперь как именно это оформлять. Когда я пишу ` if (TouchPhase.Began )` оно подчёркивает и говорит что не `bool.` Когда я пишу `TouchPhase.Began = 1`, тоже подчёркивает. Куда именно это ставить?

Comment: `if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {....`  то есть если количество прикосновений больше нуля и первое из них имеет фазу `Began`, то делать что хочется

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, благодарю, а в Update или в отдельный метод?

Comment: Как захочется. Можно в отдельный метод. а его поместить в update)) чтоб update не распухал от множства кода

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `Input.touches.Length`.